# Probability kernels can be fully described by a certain measurable function

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

I am working through some old lecture notes about stochastic processes. The author gives the following lemma there:

> Let $(S, \mathcal{S})$ be a measurable space, $(T, \mathcal{T})$ a Borel space, $\mu: S \times \mathcal{T} \to [0, 1]$ a probability kernel and $Y$ a $\mathcal{U}([0, 1])$-distributed random variable. Then there exists a $\mathcal{S} \otimes \mathcal{B}([0, 1])$-measurable function $f: S \times [0, 1] \to T$ such that
> $$
> \mu(s, A) = \mathbb{P}\left[f(s, Y) \in A \right] = \int_0^1 1_{\{f(s,\cdot) \in A \}} (u) du
> $$
> for all $s \in S$ and $A \in \mathcal{T}$.

However, the proof does not seem right. After some research I found out that it is Lemma 3.22 in Kallenberg's *Foundations of Modern Probability* (2nd edition). There proof goes as follows:

- We may assume that $T$ is a subset of $[0, 1]$. This is because by definiton of Borel spaces, there exists a Borel set $U \subset [0, 1]$ and a measurable bijection $h: T \to U$ such that the inverse $h^{-1}$ is $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \cap U$-measurable. (**I understand this.**)
- We can easily reduce this to the case $T = [0, 1]$. (**I don't understand this part.**)
- Define $$f(s, t) := \sup \left\{ x \in [0, 1]: \mu(s, [0, x]) < t \right\}$$
  and note that
  $$ f(s, t) \leq c \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \mu(s, [0,c]) \geq t \qquad \text{for all}\ c \in [0, 1].$$
- Then we have
  $$
  \mu(s,A) = \mathbb{P}[\mu(s, A) \geq Y] = \mathbb{P}[f(s, Y) \leq c] \qquad \text{for all}\ c \in [0, 1].
  $$
- $f$ is $\mathcal{S} \otimes \mathcal{B}([0, 1])$-measurable  because $$f^{-1}([0, c]) = \{ (s, t) \in S \times [0, 1] : f(s,t) \leq c \} = \{ (s, t) : \mu(s, [0, c]) -t \geq 0 \} $$
  is meausrable as the reverse image of a jointly measurable function.

**Question:** How is the second step  justified? Is it true that there is always a measurable bijective function between a Borel set $U \subset [0, 1]$ and the unit interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no bijection between, e.g., a singleton and the unit interval, but I do not think that you need it.

Note that if $m(A) = \mu(s,A)$ is a measure on $U\subset [0,1]$, then you can extend it to a measure on $([0,1],\mathcal{B}([0,1]))$ by setting $\widetilde{m}(A) = m(A\cap U)$. That is because $\mathcal{B}(U)\subseteq \mathcal{B}([0,1])$, which follows from the fact that every open set in the relative topology of $U$ is a Borel subset of $[0,1]$.

We may set $\widetilde{\mu}(x,A) = \mu(x,A\cap U)$ for Borel $A\subseteq [0,1]$ and $x\in S$. It is a probability kernel on $S\times [0,1]$, because $\mu$ is a probability kernel on $S\times U$.

So technically speaking, after the extension we are studying a kernel on $S\times [0,1]$, but all the measures "live" only on $U$ (that is, they vanish outside of it).